# What are the risks of exposing Cassandra's secured internode port in a shared private network such as DigitalOcean's?

Tags: cassandra

In Cassandra's cassandra.yaml config file, there's this:

```
# SSL port, for encrypted communication.  Unused unless enabled in
# encryption_options
# For security reasons, you should not expose this port to the internet.  Firewall it if needed.
ssl_storage_port: 7001
```

I don't know the specifics of why the Cassandra team has given this guidance, but what are the risks within a *shared private network* such as provided by Digital Ocean? VMs of other DO clients are on the some non-routed internal network. Using iptables to limit source IPs is an option.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't claim to know what the author of the comment had in mind, there are a few different ways you can set up internode encryption. If it is set up without correctly configuring truststores and require_client_auth = true then internode encryption should verify that all participating nodes are using trusted certificates which would minimise risk. If you don't use those configurations then certificates are not necessarily trusted, leaving you open to untrusted nodes joining the cluster.

There is a great, detailed article on setting this up properly here: http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2015/09/30/hardening-cassandra-step-by-step-part-1-server-to-server.html

Of course, all that said, this is security so the more layers of defence the better and so restricting by IP tables, etc is probably still a good idea.

Ben

Comment: Encryption is configured.